# Pushing to a private Docker v2 registry gives an error: Manifest invalid

Tags: docker, registry

We have a private docker registry in artifactory. 
when we try to pull the images from docker hub and try to push to the private V2 registry, it throw an error.

Manifest invalid.

i believe the docker images are coming from v1 registry in docker hub. How can i download V2 registry base images.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have permission to do this operation in the private repository?